# Non-isotopic homology spheres in $S^4$ with equal complements?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, 4-manifolds

Are there two diffeomorphic smoothly embedded homology 3-spheres $M_1^3, M_2^3 \subset S^4$ that have diffeomorphic complements but such that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are not isotopic? I would be interested in examples in other 4-manifolds as well.  I am more interested in examples where $M_1$ and $M_2$ are not smoothly isotopic (I imagine there is a difference between smooth and topological isotopy of 3-manifolds in 4-manifolds, I guess I'd love to hear about references to that as well, specifically in $S^4$).

On a more general note, what are some general ways people tend to tell apart isotopy classes of codimension one submanifolds?

Comment: In my upcomming paper I proved some of these kind of results on "exotic 3-manfiolds" in 4-manifolds (i.e two copies are topologically isotopic but not smoothly). But those 4-manifolds may have very large $b_2$. Also in my best knowledge (after emailing to a few experts), these kind of problems are not yet wel-studied.

Comment: There aren't many tools to distinguish isotopy classes of codimension $1$ submanifolds of $S^4$.   In the case of $S^1 \times D^3$ we have an invariant we call "the $W_3$ invariant" that can distinguish some isotopy classes.  This invariant has variants that apply to some submanifolds of $S^4$, but we have not completed a computation (yet).  But it gives one possibly non-trivial invariant.

Comment: Also one of my collaborator told me that Watanabe had developed some tools for $S^1\times D^3$ (maybe using theta graph techniques). I am not sure if those are similar to Budney--Gabai's invariant. We developed some gauge theoretic tools to distinguish isotopy classes. At this point I cannot tell the details as the paper is not yet in arXiv.

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee There likely is some relation, although at present Watanabe's techniques are rational homotopy techniques, while ours can also give torsion invariants.  For example, the Tom Farrell embeddings $D^{n-1} \to S^1 \times D^{n-1}$ for $n \geq 6$ appear to be detectable with our invariants. This last point should appear in our 2nd paper, which will hopefully be released soon.

Comment: @RyanBudney I have a few questions. 1) In your techniques can you tell that embedded balls are topological isotopic? 2) Do you know what happened when you stabilize $S^1\times D^3$, i.e connected sum with $S^2\times S^2$?

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee I suppose with large $b_2$, you can take one of Ruberman's exotic mapping classes and consider it applied to an appropriate embedded 3-manifold.

Comment: @user101010 Yes, but it is not obvious why the resultant two copies are not smoothly isotopic.

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee: (1) No.  These balls may very well be distinct topologically as well as smoothly. At present I do not know.  In principle we have the tools to answer these kinds of questions but we have not pushed them in that direction, yet.  My presumption is they are distinct topologically, given that's the case in high dimensions with the Hatcher-Wagoner theory, and our machinery appears to give the Hatcher-Wagoner theta invariant in high dimensions. (2) No, but that is a computation I've been thinking about.  I hope we will have an answer to that in not too long.

Comment: @RyanBudney I see, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @RyanBudney I have one more question...are the complements of the balls diffeomorphic in your construction?

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee: Yes, we construct our embeddings (for all n) $D^{n-1} \to S^1 \times D^{n-1}$ by acting on $\{1\} \times D^{n-1}$ by diffeomorphisms of $S^1 \times D^{n-1}$.  These diffeomorphisms are the identity on the boundary of the manifold.

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee: There is a structural theorem lurking beneath my previous comment.  The mapping class group of $S^1 \times D^{n-1}$ is the direct sum of the mapping class group of $D^n$ and the path components of the space of embeddings of $D^{n-1}$ in $S^1 \times D^{n-1}$ where the embeddings restrict to a fixed linear embedding on the boundary.  So any theorem about discs in $S^1 \times D^{n-1}$ is effectively a theorem about the mapping class group of this manifold.

Comment: @RyanBudney Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: I guess the boundaries of Masur manifold Akbulut corks might have this property? The double is S^4, and regluing the boundary by the involution does not extend smoothly over the cork. But maybe these two embeddings are still isotopic? The isotopy would necessarily have to induce a nontrivial mapping class of the 3-manifold. Seems unlikely though if one can find an example whose automorphism group is solely the involution. I would guess that such examples exist.

Comment: I think the example W(0,1) from this paper works. http://gokovagt.org/journal/2020/03-jggt20-akbulut-1.pdf Akbulut shows that mapping class group of the boundary is the Klein 4 group, generated by involutions S,T which do not extend over the cork. Yet gluing by either of these gives S^4. These must be distinct embeddings, since an isotopy would give a diffeomorphism which extends over the corks, which is impossible (these were shown to be strong corks by Dai-Hedden-Mallick).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [example of an Akbulut cork](http://gokovagt.org/journal/2020/03-jggt20-akbulut-1.pdf), proved to be a strong cork by [Dai-Hedden-Mallick](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.02326), $W= W(0,1)$ whose boundary $M$ is $+1$ surgery on the Stevedore knot, and has a mapping class group of order 4 generated by two involutions $S$ and $T$. If one doubles $W$ along $M$, then one gets $S^4=-W\cup W$, and hence an embedding of $M$ into $S^4$, since $W$ is a Mazur manifold (described first by [Akbulut-Kirby](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-26/issue-3/Mazur-manifolds/10.1307/mmj/1029002261.full)).
(Proposition 1 of [Mazur](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970288) proves that any such manifold has double diffeomorphic to $S^4$)

[image: involutions]

Akbulut also shows that $-W \cup_S W$ obtained by gluing two copies by $S$ is diffeomorphic to $S^4$, giving another embedding of $M$ into $S^4$, and same for $-W\cup_T W$. Suppose the two embeddings are isotopic, in particular there is a diffeomorphism taking one embedding to the other. Then this diffeomorphism takes the $W$ on each side to each other. We may think of one $W$ as fixed, and the diffeomorphism extends over the other $W$. But the other two copies of $W$ are glued by the identity and $S$ respectively, so we see that the involution $S$ extends to a diffeomorphism of $W$, a contradiction. Thus we have two  copies of $M$ embedded in $S^4$ which are not isotopic, and which have diffeomorphic complements.

One comment: if the isotopy  takes the $W$ on one side to the other copy of $W$ in such a way that the diffeomorphism is not isotopic to the identity on $M$, then it must be the involution $ST$ in the mapping class group of $M$, since $S$ and $T$ don’t extend. Then the two mapping classes will differ by $T$, which still doesn’t extend over the other copy of $W$.

Comment: Dear Professor @Ian Agol, Here what's confusing me the most... If we know that both of the copies are "diffeomorphic" to S^4, then we will have a self diffeomorphism from $f: S^4\to S^4$. Now knowing that two copies of 3-manifolds are not isotopic, doesn't that mean $f$ is not smoothly isotopic to identity and thus contradicting Smale conjecture?

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee I don’t get the logic, why is it not isotopic to the identity?

Comment: Let's say $S_1 = -W\cup_S W$ and $S_2= -W\cup_T W$. Then Both $S_1,S_2$ are diffeomorphic to $S^4$. So maybe it is not clear that how these two different identifications can give a self-diffeomorphism on $S^4$? Also is it clear that it's an "exotic" embedding, that is two copies of $Y$ are top isotopic? Maybe this is where I am getting confused.

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee If by $Y$ you mean what I am calling $M$, then the point of the answer is to show that the two copies are not isotopic. One manifold was shown to be S^4 by Mazur, one by Akbulut. So the manifolds are diffeomorphic, but not in a way that takes one copy of M to the other.

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee Also, I think that Akbulut shows that the involutions $S$ and $T$ extend to a homeomorphism of $W$, so there is a homeomorphism sending one embedded M to the other. If the space of orientation preserving homeos is connected, then the two embeddings are topologically isotopic. But I don’t know if this is the case.